# Change azure's pool permissions

Tags: node.js, azure, logging, pool

Everything is set up to enable logging normally, but there is no IISnode/ or Logging/ folder created anywhere, because of pool's writing permissions :

I get this error message every time I try to access my app in the browser:

[image]

In order to see the logs, I have to authorize my app's pool to write log files.

But I couldn't figure out where in Azure portal to edit the permissions.

I already switched on the logging:

[image]

Here is my IISNode.yml file:

```
node_env: production

loggingEnabled: true
devErrorsEnabled: true
logDirectory: iisnode
debuggingEnabled: true
maxLogFileSizeInKB: 1048
maxLogFiles: 50
```

Where is that ?

I am really stuck cause without the logs I can't figure out why can't my app launch

**Edit:**

More details:

**Node version**: 7.10.0

**Project structure**:

```
gdpr/
    web.config
    package.json    
    node_modules/
    app/
        sslCert.pem
        server.js
        app.js
        config.js
        routes.js
        knexfile.js
        migrations/
        api/
            controller.js
            handlers/
                {...several *.js}
```

**startpoint**: server.js

**config.js**:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var config = module.exports;
var PRODUCTION = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

config.express = {
    port: process.env.EXPRESS_PORT || 51082,
    ip: '127.0.0.1'
};

config.knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host: 'someHost.mysql.database.azure.com',
        user: 'someUser@gdprdataserver',
        password: 'somePw',
        database: 'gdpr',
        insecureAuth: true
    },
    debug: ['ComQueryPacket'],
    pool: {
        min: 0
    }
});


config.migrate = function(cb){
    config.knex.migrate.latest()
        .then(function() {
            cb();
        });
}


config.bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(config.knex);


if (PRODUCTION) {
    //for example
    config.express.ip = '0.0.0.0';
}
```

**server.js**:

```
var app = require('./app');
var config = require('./config');


function launchApp() {
    app.listen(config.express.port, config.express.ip, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Unable to listen for connections');
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(10);
        }
        console.log('express is listening on http://' + config.express.ip + ':' + config.express.port);
    });
}

config.migrate(launchApp);
```

**web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>        
        <webSocket enabled="false" />

        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="app/server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^app/server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="app/server.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <remove segment="bin" />
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>

        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

        <iisnode 
            watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" 
            node_env="%node_env%" 
            loggingEnabled="true" 
            logDirectory="iisnode" 
            debuggingEnabled="true" 
            maxLogFileSizeInKB="1048" 
            maxLogFiles="50" 
            devErrorsEnabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you enabled the logging of stderr and stdout from your Node.js application, you can check out logs in: `D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode` via Kudu or browse to it by going to:

```
https://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/iisnode/index.html
```

Comment: No, that's rightly my problem. The pool doesn't have the permissions to write log files, as I first wrote in my post. So even with the parameters switched on, there is NO folder created. By entering your url, I get {"Message":"'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\iisnode\\index.html' not found."}

Comment: Can you take the `web.config` file from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45193863/permissions-and-request-with-iisnode/45208082#45208082) and put it into `/wwwroot` folder?

Comment: Done but still same problem thx anyway. The port was already set on default env.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with more information about which version of Node.js you are using and some sample code?

Comment: Ok i'll will put that plus my folder structure, keep you posted

Comment: Please try to replace `process.env.EXPRESS_PORT` with `process.env.PORT` in config.js.